# Make a window topmost using a window handle

Tags: c#, windows, process

After launching an application using the Process class I'd like to make that window topmost.  Currently, my app is the topmost window so when i launch the other app it doesn't display.  One thing that came to mind is that I could set topmost = false for my application before launching the process, the problem with this is I want to give the process ample time to load up before displaying it to the user, so I'd like more control over when I switch the other application to the topmost.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to use [P/Invoke with SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos) to accopmlish this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

// Call this way:
SetWindowPos(theWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, should do the trick! Is user32 valid on 64 bit systems too?

Comment: @JamesCadd Bydefault, windows 64 bit have both 32 and 64 bit system files.