# Could anyone help to how to deal with "SwitchToThisWindow" on the process which from rundll32.exe?

Tags: rundll32

Could anyone help to how to deal with "SwitchToThisWindow" on the process which from rundll32.exe? thanks.

As below image: “Internet Properties” is under “Rundll32”,  I have PID 3368 for rundll32.exe and use below code to put the process on top. But cannot switch “Internet Properties” to top.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
SwitchToThisWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, true);

private static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool turnon);
```

[image]

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984556/switchtothiswindow) mentions an extra call to `SetWindowPos` is needed to force the window on top.

Comment: that is another method to fixed this issue. use FindWindows function. not get handle by process id, but this can fix my issue. thank you very much.