# Running exe with TopMost property only for the Owner

Tags: c#, wpf

Searched my bestfriend Google and couldn't find the answer, so I'll just ask you guys.

I created a test-app in WPF just to try something out, where there is just a button, and by clicking it I open Notepad with the following:

```
Process executable = new Process ();
        string executablePath = "notepad.exe";
        executable.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
        executable.Start ();
```

So far so good, but not exactly what I want, since I would like for Notepad to be TopMost for only the Application that called it and not for everything, which means, when I open Chrome, Paint, or any other application, Notepad shouldn't be on top of them, but for only the test-app itself.

Is there a good way to achieve that without having flickering in case I click something from the Owner?

Thank you!

Comment: No, a window created by another process cannot be an owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant has mentioned, you are trying to set a property on a `Window` that is completely outside of your application. While you *can* set the `TopMost` property of one of these `Window`s *if you have a handle for the `Window`*, I don't believe that you can set the `Owner` property in this way.

You can find out more from the [`SetWindowPos` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN. You can also find a working example of setting an external `Window` to `TopMost` using this method in the [C# make a window topmost using a window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/c-sharp-make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle) post here on StackOverflow.