# How do I show a form on screen even while playing fullscreen games?

Tags: c#, dll

I want to show text on screen while playing a fullscreen game... This is my current code, the text is displayed on the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    //info about the form location and make it invisible
    InitializeComponent();
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    BackColor = Color.Lime;
    TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    TopMost = true;
}
```

The text isn't shown when running fullscreen applications.

What can I do so it will show me the text?

Comment: I don't see a label anywhere in your code. How do you show your text?

Comment: Another guy had the same question, Dll Injection would be required: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a1ba0ae-6108-40d2-b213-19bf59f5eec8/make-for-absolute-on-top-problem-when-running-games-in-fullscreen?forum=csharpgeneral --- _(**Note** that Steam VAC reacts to Dll Injection, so you shouldn't do it if you're playing any online Steam games)_.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/c-sharp-make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle

Comment: Is there any other way? instead of the DLL injection?

Comment: I don't think so. Fullscreen applications (such as games) doesn't use the regular methods to create and render their "window" and it's contents. The reason you would have to use the (unsafe for cheat protected games) Dll Injection is because you must either host the form inside the game, or tell the game to render it on top. And neither cannot be done using external functions.