# display a popup inside external application

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing an application in which, if I press a combination of keys shows me a popup inside the form of another external application, I mean something like the "windows game menu", but I have no idea how to show the popup in the external application. I leave you an image to make you understand what I mean as a popup. sorry for my english but I do not speak.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The picture looks a bit consufisng to me.

So just to clarify you made 2 VB.net applications and you want that once you detect a key combination on application1 the application2 will show a messagebox ?

That will require a deep knowledge of programming and will involve WM_SENDMESSAGE interaction , you can find some details about the method here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage

Both application must be designed to allow this kind of interaction, the one which is sending the command request (message) and the one which is getting it.

Comment: no, i have only one vb.net application, and i'd like to show a popup similar to the one i send before in a non vb.net application (type as chrome, steam, and some more)

Comment: Perhaps there's a language barrier here. Did you mean to say that you want the pop-up to be _on top of_ the other application?

Comment: yes, it can work too, but i need it to work in fullscreen too

Comment: but it would be better inside the application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control one application form of another application without having access to its code or knowing if a queue messaging command has been set for doing it.
It is possible to program a window of your application to be shown over any other , likely this will not be working over a Directx - OpenGL full-area, i.e. when you are playing a videogame that is using the same functionality because the last one is winning.
In this case your popup will be visible barely as a flick, but considering standard form application you can make it to stand over by working with userd32.dll method 
"SetWindowPos" with the flag HWND_TOPMOST.
You will need first to detect the position of the application window, or if it is a fullscreen one you can simply detect the size of the screen and consider to place it in the center, then you can set the position of your application form "pop-up".

Details about the SetWindowPos , which is among windwows base dll but can be invoked from .net here below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos
[Make a window topmost using a window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle)